# How can I retrieve images from MYSQL- Encrypted characters error

Tags: php, mysql, image, encryption, data-retrieval

i'm working with uploading and retrieving images from database using php and mysql.I have tried the following codes below but it returns lot of encrypted characters. The data type of the image in mysql is longblob.

```
while ($getRows = mysql_fetch_array($iQuer)){
                $yyy = $getRows['user_id'];
                $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id ='".$yyy."'");
                $divider = mysql_fetch_array($get); 
                $getName = $divider['user_name'];
                $getImage = $divider['profile_pic'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><div id = 'postsdiv'>" . "<img src = ".$getImage."/> <strong>".   $getName ."</strong><br>". $getRows['post'] . "</div><br>";
                echo "</tr>"; }
```

I also tried another syntax but it returns nothing:

```
while ($getRows = mysql_fetch_array($iQuer)){
                $yyy = $getRows['user_id'];
                $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id ='".$yyy."'");
                $divider = mysql_fetch_array($get); 
                $getName = $divider['user_name'];
                $getImage = $divider['profile_pic'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> <img src='data:image/png;base64,'" . base64_encode($getImage) . " />'"
                echo "<td><div id = 'postsdiv'>" . "<strong>". $getName ."</strong><br>". $getRows['post'] . "</div><br>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

```
$getImage = $divider['profile_pic'];
header("content-type:image/jpeg"); // Can you add this line

echo $getImage;
```

Comment: Hello sir, it only returns an empty image, though there is existing image in my database.

Comment: which datatype that image?

Comment: am asking image data type jpg/png??